# how to refactor this Haskell chain of functions code?

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, refactoring, idioms

I have some software design experience, and I am learning Haskell now. In many real world software developments, one faces a situation like the one given, for instance, below:

Suppose, I have this code

```
f1 a b c d = e 
 where
  e1 = f2 b c (f3 a)
  e2 = f4 d
  e = e1 + e2

f2 b c d = n + c + d
 where
  n = f5 b

f5 n = n*n

f3 a = a * 2

f4 a = a + 3
```

Now if I want to change f5 so that it takes yet another parameter, I will have to change all the chain of functions right upto f1.
It can be done as shown below. Note the added parameter x.

```
f1 a b c d x = e -- f1 needs to be changed
 where
  e1 = f2 b c (f3 a) x
  e2 = f4 d
  e = e1 + e2

f2 b c d x = n + c + d -- f2 needs to be changed
 where
  n = f5 b x

f5 n x = n*n -- f5 changed (**bang**)

f3 a = a * 2

f4 a = a + 3
```

Is this a normal Haskell way of doing this type of thing or is there a better (more Haskell-ish) way?
I know such a change in API will disturb the client code, but how the impact can be kept minimum and is there any Hasekll way for it?

On a more general level: How well does Haskell perform in such cases (especially taking into consideration its *immutable state* feature)? What has it to offer the developers in this regard? Or is it that Haskell has got no role, per se, to play in this and that this is just a difficult software engineering problem (no such thing as *future proof*) that we have to keep up with?

I apologize for asking more than one question in a single post, but I cannot help as these are related to each other. Also, I could not find similar question asked, sorry if I might have missed it.

Comment: Well, you can always change the type signature and the arguments list (you are writing type signatures, aren't you?), then see where the compiler complains.  Fix the first spot, then go back to step 2 until all errors are exhausted.  If you have a common set of arguments that gets passed to many functions, it would probably be better to make a new data type to hold all those values, then you can avoid changing the function arguments and instead just change the definition of that type.  This is a software problem, not really a Haskell one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is bundle up parameters like this into a single parameter object, as bhelkir suggests in a comment. If you add a new parameter to this object you will still need to change the client code that calls `f1`, and change direct consumers of that new parameter (here, `f5`), but those are both unavoidable: someone has to provide an `x` at some point, and you need it to be the client; and you have to consume the `x` somehow otherwise why are you adding it to begin with?

But, you can avoid changing intermediary functions like `f1` and `f2`, because they can ignore the new fields they don't care about. And you can get a little fancy by using the `Applicative` instance for `((->) t)` (generally called `Reader`) to pass along this object, rather than doing it manually. Here is one way to write that:

```
module Test where
import Control.Applicative

data Settings = Settings {getA :: Int,
                          getB :: Int,
                          getC :: Int,
                          getD :: Int}
f1 :: Settings -> Int
f1 = liftA2 (+) f2 f4
-- f1 = do
--   e1 <- f2
--   e2 <- f4
--   return $ e1 + e2

f2 :: Settings -> Int
-- probably something clever with liftA3 and (+) is possible here too
f2 s = f5 s + getC s + f3 s

f3 :: Settings -> Int
f3 = liftA (* 2) getA

f4 :: Settings -> Int
f4 = liftA (+ 3) getD

f5 :: Settings -> Int
-- f5 = liftA (join (*)) getB -- perhaps a bit opaque
f5 = liftA square getB
  where square b = b * b
```

Now, this has its pluses and its minuses: the logic that was in `f1` (ie, knowing that you need to call `f3` with `a`) has moved into `f3` itself, and this will happen for any function that originally read a parameter and mucked with it before passing it along to some subsidiary function. That may be clearer than the original, or it may obscure the intent behind `f1`, depending on your problem domain. You can always write a function more explicitly, eg by having it modify the passed-in `Settings` object to change its `a` field before passing it along, as I did with `f2` as an example. More generally, you can write any function in whichever style is most convenient for it: do-notation, applicative functions, or plain old pattern-matching on the record object being passed in.

But the big plus is that it's very easy to add a new parameter: you just add a field to the `Settings` record, and read it in the function that needs it:

```
module Test where
import Control.Applicative

data Settings = Settings {getA :: Int,
                          getB :: Int,
                          getC :: Int,
                          getD :: Int,
                          getX :: Int}
f1 :: Settings -> Int
f1 = liftA2 (+) f2 f4
-- f1 = do
--   e1 <- f2
--   e2 <- f4
--   return $ e1 + e2

f2 :: Settings -> Int
-- probably something clever with liftA3 and (+) is possible here too
f2 s = f5 s + getC s + f3 s

f3 :: Settings -> Int
f3 = liftA (* 2) getA

f4 :: Settings -> Int
f4 = liftA (+ 3) getD

f5 :: Settings -> Int
f5 = liftA2 squareAdd getB getX
  where squareAdd b x = b * b + x
```

Note that everything is the same except the `data Settings` and `f5`.

Comment: The neat thing about this is that it works well with defaults with respect to future API changes, too.  So if you had a `defaultSettings`, you can have the user do `defaultSettings { getC  = 3 }` to modify `getC`.  The best part is that if you decided to add, say, a `getE` field, the `defaultSettings { getC = 3 }` code still works :)